# Inno Setup to create a user in Windows

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I´m start user in inno Setup, but I need to create an user in Windows with a password that need input during installation.

Like in `CheckSerial` where is needed input a name, I need someway to cap this name and other field to insert a password.

On DOS I can create a user with:

```
net user USER PWD /add /fullname:"USER" /comment:"TEST" /expires:never /passwordchg:no
```

I got it in

```
[Run]
Filename: net.exe; parameters: "user USER PWD /add /fullname:""USER"" /comment:""TEST"" /expires:never /passwordchg:no"
```

But I need input name and password of this user. I think it's possible in `[Code]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great example on how to get user data from a custom page and use it with `"{code:FunctionName|Argument}"` in other sections: https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeDlg.iss

Short overview:

- Add a `TInputQueryWizardPage` in `InitializeWizard`.

  ```pascal
  [Code]
  var
    UserPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

  procedure InitializeWizard;
  begin
    UserPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'Personal Information', 'Who are you?',
      'Please specify your name and password.');
    UserPage.Add('Name:', False);
    UserPage.Add('Password:', True);
  end;
  ```
- Add a function called `GetUser` like that returns the requested value:

  ```pascal
  function GetUser(Param: String): String;
  begin
    if Param = 'Name' then
      Result := UserPage.Values[0]
    else if Param = 'Password' then
      Result := UserPage.Values[1];
  end;
  ```
- Use the input data in the `Run` command:

  ```
  [Run]
  Filename: net.exe; parameters: "user {code:GetUser|Name} {code:GetUser|Password} /add /fullname:""USER"" /comment:""TEST"" /expires:never /passwordchg:no"
  ```