# Query list of Windows accounts in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my Inno Setup project I need to allow the user to choose an account from the list of all local accounts on a custom page. The selected account will be used to install a service with custom credential.
How can I make this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WMI `Win32_UserAccount` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount) to query the list of accounts.

```
[Run]
Filename: sc.exe; Parameters: ... {code:GetAccount}
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  AccountPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  WMIService: Variant;
  WbemLocator: Variant;
  WbemObjectSet: Variant;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Log('InitializeWizard');
  AccountPage := CreateInputOptionPage(
    wpSelectTasks, 'Service account', '', 'Please select account for the service:',
    True, True);

  WbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  WMIService := WbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2');
  WbemObjectSet :=
    WMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount');
  if not VarIsNull(WbemObjectSet) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to WbemObjectSet.Count - 1 do
    begin
      AccountPage.Add(WbemObjectSet.ItemIndex(I).Caption);
    end;
    AccountPage.SelectedValueIndex := 0;
  end;
end;

function GetAccount(Param: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to AccountPage.CheckListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if AccountPage.Values[I] then Result := AccountPage.CheckListBox.Items[I];
  end;
end;
```

[image]

---

Related questions:

- [Inno Setup Create individual shortcuts on all desktops of all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35224772/850848)
- [Inno Setup to create a user in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33045837/850848)