# Inno Install for multiple users in a Local PC

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup

The requirement is, in a shared PC admin want to install the software for selected users if AppData folder exist for the user. Users can be local or remote but the profile data should exist in the local PC

I have tried few solution from SO, but couldn't figured out a right solution

[Solution 1 :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65249995/query-list-of-windows-accounts-in-inno-setup) This returns all the remote users, many doesn't have profile data in the local PC

Solution 2 : Iteratre through all the profiles available under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` in the registry

Is there any better efficient way than Soultion 2?

Comment: Got your question @MartinPrikryl, it copies the files to AppData folder only nothing to do with registry keys

Comment: And do you find inefficient about the *"Solution 2"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl instead of Solution 2, I am thinking to loop through %SystemDrive%\Users drive and find the user folders and display it for selection

Comment: Well, your choice. I just do not see what is more efficient about iterating subfolders than about iterating registry keys.